# Jquery+PHP+Mysql: Change value of input field from change on Select Box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want the user to be able to select an option, which would change the value of an input text field. It should load the value from PHP+MYSQL depending on the option.

Basically, getting option value, pushing to a php file to get a return on value for the input text field

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to send a post request with the selected option, and then return some JSON data which could then be placed into the input field.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/